# Laravel 4 - get data from pivot table

Tags: laravel-4, pivot-table

I have two tables ´actividad´ and ´ficha´ (a kind of album). Every 'actividad' can appear in many 'ficha', and every 'ficha' can have many 'actividad'. So, their relationship is `belongsToMany`.

I'm working in a index page, where I show a list of 'actividads'. I actually got the `actividad_id`, the `user_id` and a list of 'fichas' he (the user) has created. And I want to check if any of his fichas contains this actividad.

I don't know how to do it...

Any idea?? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Define relationship in both Model, by doing so you can run queries both way. Check out the Laravel Documentation [Working With Pivot Tables](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to retrieve the `ficha` of a certain `user` with id `$id` that has a specific `actividad` with id `$actividad_id`:

```
$user = User::find($id);
$ficha = $user->ficha()->whereHas('actividad', function($q) use ($actividad_id)
{
    $q->where('actividad_id', '=', $actividad_id);
})->get();
```